# Render SharePoint 2010 web part inside iFrame (non SharePoint page)

Tags: web-part, document-library, web-services, iframe

I'm investigating the possibility to show a Web Part inside an iFrame - in a non SharePoint environment.

We want to build an integration between a CRM sytem and SharePoint. We want to work with SharePoint documents from the CRM, but still let SharePoint handle all the documents.

Therefore I would appreciate if anyone could help med with:

- Is it possible to render a Web part inside an Iframe - non SharePoint
  site?
- Are there any know restrictions/difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CRM perspective, no idea! But I guess, basically, you can create a page in SharePoint where you provision your webpart.

Then you can create an iframe in CRM with the url to the `pageUrl + "isDlg=1"` which will hide the header and left nav etc.

You must, though, make sure that all users that will be able to see this in CRM also has access to the SharePoint page (to not get an access denied)

Comment: I dont think we can put a sharepoint webpart on a non-sharepoint page. can we?

Comment: From the CRM prespective, its a custom CRM so everything is possible :) So from what you think there are no restrictions, from the SharePoint part, of displaying a web part inside a IFrame. Thank you.

Comment: variable: So you have different thoughts? I've tried to find answers like this. Don't want to stumble upon a basic issue when taking this further. Do you have any link or explanations that you want to share?

Comment: @variable, who said it should be anything else than a SharePoint page?

Comment: Please read the brackets in the question.

Comment: To clarify. The web part will of course be placed on a share point page. We want to Iframe this web part / page inside our custom CRM, which is of course not a SharePoint page :) Thx!

Comment: Ok, if the iframe will go on the CRM then I think there should be no problem, provided there are permissions for the loggedin user :)

Comment: With the Excel Services, this still didn't work for me.

Comment: @wilsjd My answer is not at all targeted to Excel Services, but a basic CRM integration..

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2010 there won't be an issue in rendering regular pages in an iFrame, but for SharePoint 2013 (and also Excel Services pages) you'll probably run into **X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN** issues.

For SharePoint 2013 it is the preferred way to add `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />` to the page you're framing. (http://styledpoint.com/blog/including-sharepoint-2013-in-an-iframe-without-x-frame-options-error/)

For Excel Services in SharePoint 2010 you could use an HttpModule that removes this header. (http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2012/01/03/sharepoint-2010-office-web-apps-and-iframes.aspx)

Comment: Ok good to know! Thx